# My samsung galaxy player 5 does not connect to the internet, but apparently connects to my router

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, samsung-galaxy-player

I have a cisco  linksys E1500 router, secured with WPA/WPA2 PSK. My samsung galaxy player 5, fresh out of the box, conencts to it but cannot access the internet. Based on [this thread](http://www.anythingbutipod.com/forum/showthread.php?t=67240), I made myself a static IP of 192.168.1.12. It still doesn't work. This [other thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1371794) talks about MAC cloning, but I'm not sure how to do that

EDIT: I remembered we have a messed up router/provider. We have to use DHCP addresses only, and set the DNS servers manually. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's something the Android system does not provide by default. But you might take a look at e.g. [Zakus WiFi Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zakus.wifiprofiles), which lets you create profiles by access point (Android itself has only global settings here, which would apply to all WiFi APs you connect to):

[image: Zakus Profile] [image: Zakus Assign]

As I never used this myself, I'm not sure whether it only deals with static IPs, or can handle DHCP with special settings as well. The app description doesn't explicitly state this.

Alternatively, [IP Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monkelabs.ipmanager) might prove helpful. It says to manage *different IP profiles for different access points*, but unfortunately gives no closer details (and the screenshots don't tell that much). Still worth a try, as it sounds promising.

Comment: How do I install anything without internet?

Comment: Don't you have a data plan, so you could use the mobile data connection? In that case you need to obtain the `.apk` (e.g. asking the developer for it), save it to your computer, use the USB connection to transfer it to your device, and then install it. Alternatively, use a friends WiFi once, or any other WiFi AP (e.g. from a local Internet Café or the like). As I understood, you only have this problem with your local WiFi, not general?

Comment: No, it's a galaxy player. It's not a phone.

Comment: Oh, true, didn't realize I could go to a friend... ^^

Comment: Yeah, that was so simple it *had* to be missed :) Good luck!

Comment: Izzy: Ok, installed both of those, neither of them have DHCP only. They do what they say and make static IP switching easy, but not more.

Comment: Sorry to read that! Is your device rooted? If so, take a look at [Set DNS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.mytechie.setDNS). After a longer search on the playstore, I've also found [DNS Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eddypcz.dnschanger), which sounds as if it could solve your problem (only setting a custom DNS, and leave all else to DHCP). Again root needed. 3rd: [DNS Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.daingo.dnssetting) doesn't talk about root.